# Replace comma from numbers only

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which contains numbers as well as strings like:

```
COST
------------
1,350.45
N,A
11,340.65
A,B,C.30
Some Text 1,245.50
```

I want to remove all commas from numbers only and not the string to generate output like below:

```
COST
------------
1350.45
N,A
11340.65
A,B,C.30
Some Text 1,245.50
```

I tried using below code but it removes comma from string also

```
regexp_replace(df("COST"), "\\p{Sc}|,", "")
```

is there any better approach or a regular expression to make it work ?

Comment: `1,245.50` also has comma between digits only

Comment: yes. But since it contains String, i do not want to remove comma from there

Comment: I think you should separate it into two step. Step 1 is detect if the string not included characters in it. And then use this regex to match the comma (?<=\d),(?=\d{3})

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(df("COST"), """\G([0-9]+),+(?=[0-9.,]*$)""", "$1")`

Comment: if you familiar with csv, you may notice that string cells often escaped. Escaping has a very good reason. How it's possible to define that 1,245.50 are 2 numbers, not one, in your example? Maybe `Try(BigDecimal(str.replaceAll(",", "")).getOrElse(str)` will suit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex replacement in scala (or Java):

```bash
regexp_replace(df("COST"), "\G(\d+),(?=\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$)", "$1")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Ijja0/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\\G`: Match start position or end position of the previous match
- `(\\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture in group #1
- `,`; Match a comma
- `(?=\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$)`: Is a lookahead to assert that we have only a number containing digits, comma and decimal point ahead of us
- `$1` is the replacement to put the captured digits back in the replacement

Comment: Note that `(?:^|\\G)` = `\\G` in this code. `(?:^|\\G)` is only needed for Regex101 demo where the text string is a single input. Also, the `regexp_replace(df("COST"), "(?>^|\\G)(\\d+),", "$1")` does not make sure the whole text is a number, it will also trigger on `1,255.50 Some Text`.

Comment: Thanks, fair point @WiktorStribiżew,  I have edited it now.

Comment: @anubhava I like the `\G` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [try_to_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#try_to_number) function to format number followed by `case` statement to catch `string` values

```
val caseExpr: String =
"""
    CASE WHEN try_to_number(cost, '99,99,999.99') IS NOT NULL
    THEN try_to_number(cost, '99,99,999.99')
    ELSE cost END
"""
```

```
df
.withColumn("new_cost", expr(caseExpr))
.show(false)
```

Output

```
+------------------+------------------+
|cost              |new_cost          |
+------------------+------------------+
|1,350.45          |1350.45           |
|N,A               |N,A               |
|11,340.65         |11340.65          |
|A,B,C.30          |A,B,C.30          |
|Some Text 1,245.50|Some Text 1,245.50|
+------------------+------------------+
```